# Effect of difficulty on mass effect 3 story line

Tags: mass-effect-3

Does the difficulty effect the storyline in mass effect 3 in anyway. Is it just me or did the dialogue options in mass effect 2 effect your story playout more than mass effect 3?

Answer (score 6):

No, the difficulty affects combat, not the storyline or your choices. There is a mode that makes story decisions for you, but it is not related to difficulty.

Comment: i really wasn't expecting it too, i just felt like i flew through ME3 compared to ME2 and seemed like your choices had more of an effect in ME2.

Comment: @JaredMedellin that's because that is the case. Mass Effect 3 started tying up loose ends reasonably early into the story, resulting in the number of available decisions being quite a bit lower than in previous games.

Comment: @JaredMedellin - It seems like that because there are not loyality missions in ME3.  Although what you do have is missions depending on your choices gets you readyness points.  You could in theory fail at certain objectives during a mission which results in a overall lower readyness rating.